# How to create Date object from the string date in Javascript for the first years of A.D?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, date

I have next date string:

"Thu Nov 14 0002 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)"

and I'm trying to convert it to the Date object:

```
date = new Date("Thu Nov 14 0002 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)")  
=> Invalid Date {}
```

and it doesn't work. And

```
date = new Date("Thu Nov 14 2 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)")  
=> Invalid Date {}
```

doesn't work too

but

```
date = new Date("Thu Nov 14 2002 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)")
```

works

Does anyone know an elegant way to parse it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set any date. including minutes,hours and milliseconds directly using a timestamp-
    dates before 1970 are negative integers.

```
alert(new Date(-62076675540000).toUTCString());

// >> Wed, 13 Nov 0002 23:01:00 GMT

Or you can set the date as a string by replacing the years to make it over 1000,
then subtracting the amount you added  with setFullYear()

var d=new Date("Thu Nov 14 1002 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)")
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()-1000)
alert(d.toUTCString())

// >> Wed, 13 Nov 0002 23:01:00 GMT

You can automate a conversion to timestamps-

var s="Thu Nov 14 0002 01:01:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)";
var y=s.split(' ')[3], y2=5000+(+y);
var d=new Date(s.replace(y,y2));
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()-5000)
var timestamp=+d;
alert(timestamp)
// >> -62076675540000
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript dates are based on a count of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, 00:00:00.000 UTC. Dates before that are not defined.

<strike>You'll have to come up with your own way to represent such dates.</strike>

*edit* — well having said that, Javascript seems willing to represent dates with weirdly large negative offfsets from the epoch; offsets that don't fit in 32 bit integers. I suspect that the root cause of your date is simply that the format it's in upsets the parser.  There's supposed to be a comma after the day abbreviation.

Another problem (boy this is way more interesting than I thought) is that in Chrome and Firefox at least any year before 100 is treated as an abbreviation for a year in the 20th century.

*edit again* — according to the Mozilla docs, a Date can be anything in the range of -100,000,000 days before the epoch to 100,000,000 days after it.